# Renewing my Indian passport in India as an NRI

Tags: usa, passports, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I hold an Indian passport that's due to expire on 20th of January 2019. I've come on a vacation to India now (Dec 2018). I haven't visited India for a year and a half until now, so officially, I am deemed as an NRI.

The address on my current passport and my Aadhar Card have changed, ie my permanent address in India is no longer the address mentioned on my Aadhar. So, I do not have an address proof for my current permanent residence in India.

Is it still possible for me to renew my passport in India? I am unsure as to what address to mention as "Present Address" on the application [whether it has to be an address where police verification can take place in which case I can't provide my US address].

If not, how do I get a new passport?

Another related question: In case I am not able to renew my passport in India, would it still be possible to travel to the US with a passport that's due to expire in a few weeks? [I read the 6-month validity rule and it seems like India is exempt from it, but not sure what the border control folks are like regarding situations like these]

Would appreciate any help because of the emergency (need to travel back to the US by the first week of Jan).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I read the 6-month validity rule and it seems like India is exempt from it`. That is correct and [codified in the Foreign Affairs Manual](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2). You should not have any problems with that at entry and if you do, have a copy of the reference.

Comment: My understanding is that NRI is only for income tax purposes. It has no bearing on your application for a passport.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen you are correct about the 6 month validity rule. There are however other practical issues, many airlines require that your passport be valid for more than 6 months as one of the conditions of carriage. The other issue is that the OP will not be allowed to stay in the US for longer than their passport expiry on their I-94 unless they are a Green Card holder.

Comment: @nikhil it depends. If he’s a US permanent resident the airline will not hold him to the 6 month rule. It’s imperative he gets a new passport before returning if he’s not a green card holder. In June 2007 I was denied boarding by Delta on my way back to the USA because my passport validity had only 5 more months to run. Terrible experience, had to stay another 3 weeks sorting out a new passport, change fees, and nearly missed out on a crucial summer internship.

Answer (score 2):

For renewal of passport, you usually doesn't have to go through police verification. It will be done within short amount of time and depending on where you are, you will get it via post to the address specified.

If you can arrange to collect from your old permanent address, no issues.

But, if you can't, you need to submit a copy of address proof to change the address upon renewal and you will require to go through police verification. List of acceptable address proof below.

https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/popuponline/AttachmentAdvisorSub?subDocID=7001&amp%3BconfirmDOB=7001